# How to recover a corrupted "tar.gz" file

Tags: tar, data-recovery, gzip, corruption

I suddenly needed to recover an old `tar.gz` file, but as soon as I execute so:

```
tar -zxvf filename.tar.gz
```

I get this:

```
gzip: stdin: invalid compressed data--format violated  
tar: Child returned status 1  
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

Comment: Is that really a gzipped tarball?  Try `file` command on it first.

Comment: Yes, it has happened to me more than once that I got a `.tar.gz` which was really a `.tar`, and once even a PDF.

Answer (score 13):

What you should try is the following:

1. Use `file` command on the archive to see if it's recognized as `gzip`-ped data.
2. Run `strace gunzip` on the file.  This will print the last bytes read from the file which might help you identify the point in file where corruption occurs.
3. Run a debug build of `gunzip` under `gdb`.  Try to correct the corrupted section (you have to be extra lucky to be able to do that) and see if it can continue to the end of the file.

Depending on the nature of corruption, you might or might not be able to recover your data.

Comment: `gunzip filename.tar.gz` worked for me.

Answer (score 6):

Some info about how recovery works can be found at [Recovering a damaged .gz file](https://web.archive.org/web/20180708075208/http://www.gzip.org/recover.txt).

There also is a tool that helps you doing this: [gzip Recovery Toolkit aka gzrecover](https://github.com/arenn/gzrt).

Answer (score 6):

Full recovery is not possible. Formats like .zip provide better protection and recovery options, but not full either.

**.tar.gz** lumps all files together and then applies a compression. **.zip** restarts compression for each file. Therefore in .zip file a damage done to compressed block only affects the file to which this block belongs. In .tar.gz the damage will affect all subsequent files until compression is somehow restarted.

Comment: that I was thinking, good explanation thx! I wonder if there are other formats as good as zip (but with better compression), but zip is always recognized everywhere and is probably the best option concerning recovery.

Answer (score 2):

Run `zcat bad.tar.gz > some.tar`, and extract that. Going past the corrupted part of the file *will* be tricky. The man page gives pointers to the format, but I'd look for other options in Google.

Are you sure this is compressed with gzip? It might be complaining because it doesn't understand the format...

Answer (score 1):

All recpies apply only for extracting info from begin of file to point where error occured, or where file is cutted.

Unfortunately no one recipie describies how to recover part of file/stream after corruption area. Has anybody that recipie?

Answer (score 1):

use this one : https://github.com/arenn/gzrt

```
gzrecover foo.tar.gz
cpio -F foo.tar.recovered -i -v
```

Comment: Your command results in a `cpio: illegal option -- F` error message.

Comment: cpio --help give you the option :  -F, --file=[[USER@]HOST:]FILE-NAME
                             Use this FILE-NAME instead of standard input or
                             output. Optional USER and HOST specify the user
                             and host names in case of a remote archive

Comment: You are not talking abpout `cpio`, but about a clone with vendor specific options, see e.g. http://schillix.sourceforge.net/man/man1/cpio.1.html If ypou however talk about a clone instead of the original, you should mention which clone you are using.

Comment: @schilly, i'm talking about  `cpio` include in debian. GNU cpio : [link](http://www.gnu.org/software/cpio/)