# Modify the data type from .tar file and how to recover a corrupted one

Tags: tar, data-recovery, gzip, corruption

Like the original question bellow, I need to recover a corrupted tar file. But after run:

> file file.tgz

I got this return:

> file.tgz: data

My question is about this return above and how to change to `gzip` or something similar to zip/tar files.

Original question: [How to recover a corrupted "tar.gz" file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17452/how-to-recover-a-corrupted-tar-gz-file)

Comment: More informative should be `mimetype file.tgz` which should return "application/x-compressed-tar" - but its only looking at the first few bytes. If the mimetype isn't recognised, this is a seriously corrupt file.

Answer (score 0):

The `file` command reads the beginning of the file (or any part of the file, but it's usually the beginning) to guess what it contains. It isn't some kind of metadata that you can change. The beginning of the file does not look like a compressed or uncompressed archive, or like any other common format. If you think this is a corrupted tar file, you need to look at it and understand the format if you want to have any chance of recovering part of its content.

Recovering the data from other means is very likely to be easier than extracting data from a damaged file if you neither have experience in data recovery nor know what type of damage it suffered.